# Prevent navigateurl property from firing and instead go to the click event

Tags: asp.net, navigateurl

I've a Panelbar with some PanelItems in it. The PanelItems have got a navigateUrl property.
Whenever I right click, and select the "Open in New tab/Window", I want the page to be redirected to the navigateUrl link.

But when i do a normal left click on the item, I dont want it to redirect to the navigateUrl. Instead I want it to the click event property of the PanelItem.

Is there anyway, I can prevent the navigation from happening. I think I've to do something in the OnClientItemClick event, but I dont know how can I prevent the navigation from happening there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a NavigateUrl (as it causes a navigation everytime) - you can use custom attributes and set to each panel item the url to navigate to in the custom attribute. That way the ItemClick event will be fired every time you click on a panelbar item.

Take a look at [this Telerik demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/panelbar/examples/applicationscenarios/customattributes/defaultcs.aspx) for an example of Custom Attributes.